# How can I print only integers/numbers from string

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-3.x, int, return

Hello I am fairly new at programming and python and I have a question.

How would I go about printing or returning only numbers from a string

For example:

```
"Hu765adjH665Sdjda"
```

output:

```
"765665"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **re.sub** to remove any character that is not a number.

```
import re

string = "Hu765adjH665Sdjda"
string = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', string)
print string
#'765665'
```

`re.sub` scan the string from left to right. everytime it finds a character that is not a number it replaces it for the empty string (which is the same as removing it for all practical purpose).

Comment: Hey thanks for the prompt reply ! Could you explain what is going on in here thanks ! :D

Comment: can this also be used for alphabets?

Comment: like if I just want alphabets and not numbers... so I can change it to [^a-z] ... and that will work?

Comment: oh one last question... sorry to bother u... how can I get this working for Uppercase and lower case alphabets

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "Hu765adjH665Sdjda"
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c in '0123456789')
'765665'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a='a345g5'



for i in a:
    if int(i.isnumeric()):
        print(i,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try filter

```
>>> str='1qaz2wsx3edc4rfv5tgb6yhn7ujm8ik9ol'
>>> print str
1qaz2wsx3edc4rfv5tgb6yhn7ujm8ik9ol
>>> filter(lambda x:x>='0' and x<='9', str)
'123456789'
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the prompt answer !!

One more thing, could you also explain whats going on here?

Comment: Oh and I am getting this error:  <filter object at 0x00000000031FBB00>

Comment: Don't use names like `str` since they override functions like `str`

Comment: Pretty straight forward, `filter` takes a predicate and a collection of inputs and returns only those which the predicate evaluates as true

Comment: what does this 'lambda' function do?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda). Just syntactic sugar for a function, it can make the code shorter but sometimes it becomes less readable, especially when abused.

Answer (score 0):

```py
sentence = "Hu765adjH665Sdjda"

for number in sentence:
    if number in "0123456789":
        print(number)
```